# Warning: Illegal string offset 'Andorra' in ... on line 106

Tags: plugin-development

Complete Code.

```
// Set UI labels for Custom Post Type
$labels = array(
'name'                => _x( 'Events', 'evn_calendar'),
'singular_name'       => _x( 'events', 'evn_calendar'),
'menu_name'           => __( 'Events', 'evn_calendar' ),
'parent_item_colon'   => __( 'Parent Event', 'evn_calendar' ),
'all_items'           => __( 'All Events', 'evn_calendar' ),
'view_item'           => __( 'View Event', 'evn_calendar' ),
'add_new_item'        => __( 'Add New Event', 'evn_calendar' ),
'add_new'             => __( 'Add New', 'evn_calendar' ),
'edit_item'           => __( 'Edit Event', 'evn_calendar' ),
'update_item'         => __( 'Update Event', 'evn_calendar' ),
'search_items'        => __( 'Search Event', 'evn_calendar' ),
'not_found'           => __( 'Not Found', 'evn_calendar' ),
'not_found_in_trash'  => __( 'Not found in Trash', 'evn_calendar' ),
);

// Set other options for Custom Post Type

$args = array(
'label'               => __( 'events', 'evn_calendar' ),
'description'         => __( 'Event news and reviews', 'evn_calendar' ),
'labels'              => $labels,
// Features this CPT supports in Post Editor
'supports'            => array( 'title', 'editor', 'excerpt', 'author', 'thumbnail', 'comments', 'revisions', ),
// You can associate this CPT with a taxonomy or custom taxonomy. 
'taxonomies'          => array( 'genres' ),
/* A hierarchical CPT is like Pages and can have
* Parent and child items. A non-hierarchical CPT
* is like Posts.
*/ 
'hierarchical'        => false,
'public'              => true,
'show_ui'             => true,
'show_in_menu'        => true,
'show_in_nav_menus'   => true,
'show_in_admin_bar'   => true,
'menu_position'       => 20,
'can_export'          => true,
'has_archive'         => true,
'exclude_from_search' => false,
'publicly_queryable'  => true,
'capability_type'     => 'post',
);

// Registering your Custom Post Type
register_post_type( 'events', $args );



function eventcalendar_add_meta_box() {
$screens = array( 'events' );
foreach ( $screens as $screen ) {
add_meta_box(
'Event Information',
'Event Information',
'eventcalendar_show_custom_meta_box',
$screen,
'normal',
'high'
);
}
}
add_action( 'add_meta_boxes', 'eventcalendar_add_meta_box' );
function eventcalendar_show_custom_meta_box( $post ) {


wp_nonce_field( 'evn_from_date', 'evn_from_date_nonce' );
$from_date = get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_evn_from_date', true );
echo '<label for="evn_from_date">'; _e( 'When', 'event-calendar-plugin' ); echo '</label> ';
echo '<input type="date" id="evn_from_date" name="evn_from_date" value="' . esc_attr( $from_date ) . '" size="25" />';

wp_nonce_field( 'evn_from_time', 'evn_from_time_nonce' );
$from_time = get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_evn_from_time', true );
echo '<input type="time" id="evn_from_time" name="evn_from_time" value="' . esc_attr( $from_time ) . '" size="25" />';


wp_nonce_field( 'evn_to_date', 'evn_to_date_nonce' );
$from_date = get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_evn_to_date', true );
echo '<label for="evn_to_date">'; _e( 'To', 'event-calendar-plugin' ); echo '</label> ';
echo '<input type="date" id="evn_to_date" name="evn_to_date" value="' . esc_attr( $from_date ) . '" size="25" />';

wp_nonce_field( 'evn_to_time', 'evn_to_time_nonce' );
$from_time = get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_evn_to_time', true );
echo '<input type="time" id="evn_to_time" name="evn_to_time" value="' . esc_attr( $from_time ) . '" size="25" />';



$request  = wp_safe_remote_get(plugins_url('/js/latest.json', __FILE__));                  
$data = wp_remote_retrieve_body( $request );
$data = json_decode($data);

wp_nonce_field( 'evn_timezone', 'evn_timezone_nonce' );
$evn_timezone = get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_evn_timezone', true );


echo '<select id="evn_timezone" name="evn_timezone" >';

foreach ($data->countries as $country) {

$selected = ( $country[ $country->name ] == esc_attr( $country->name ) ) ? ' selected="selected"' : '';

printf( '<option value="%s(%s)"%s>%s</option>', $country->abbr, $country->name, $selected, $country->name );
}

echo '</select>';


wp_nonce_field( 'evn_all_day', 'evn_all_day_nonce' );
$evn_all_day = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'evn_all_day', true );
echo '<input type="checkbox" id="evn_all_day" name="evn_all_day" value="' . esc_attr( $evn_all_day ) . '"  />';
echo '<label for="evn_all_day">'; _e( 'All day?', 'event-calendar-plugin' ); echo '</label> ';



wp_nonce_field( 'evn_location', 'evn_location_nonce' );
$evn_location = get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_evn_location', true );
echo '<br><label for="evn_location">'; _e( 'Event Location', 'event-calendar-plugin' ); echo '</label> ';
echo '<input type="text" id="evn_location" name="evn_location" value="' . esc_attr( $evn_location ) . '" size="100" />';


wp_nonce_field( 'evn_link', 'evn_link_nonce' );
$evn_link = get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_evn_link', true );
echo '<br><label for="evn_link">'; _e( 'Link', 'event-calendar-plugin' ); echo '</label> ';
echo '<input type="text" id="evn_link" name="evn_link" value="' . esc_attr( $evn_link ) . '" size="100" placeholder=""/>';

}
function eventcalendar_save_meta_box_data( $post_id ) {
if ( ! isset( $_POST['evn_from_date_nonce'] ) && 
! isset( $_POST['evn_from_time_nonce'] )  &&  
! isset( $_POST['evn_to_date_nonce'] ) && 
! isset( $_POST['evn_to_time_nonce'] )  &&  
! isset( $_POST['evn_location_nonce'] ) && 
! isset( $_POST['evn_timezone'] ) && 
! isset( $_POST['evn_link'] ))

{
return;
}
if (! wp_verify_nonce( $_POST['evn_from_date_nonce'], 'evn_from_date' ) && 
! wp_verify_nonce( $_POST['evn_from_time_nonce'], 'evn_from_time' ) && 
! wp_verify_nonce( $_POST['evn_to_date_nonce'], 'evn_to_date' ) && 
! wp_verify_nonce( $_POST['evn_to_time_nonce'], 'evn_to_time' ) && 

! wp_verify_nonce( $_POST['evn_timezone_nonce'], 'evn_timezone' ) && 

! wp_verify_nonce( $_POST['evn_location_nonce'], 'evn_location' ) &&
! wp_verify_nonce( $_POST['evn_link_nonce'], 'evn_link' )  ) {
return;
}
if ( defined( 'DOING_AUTOSAVE' ) && DOING_AUTOSAVE ) {
return;
}
if ( isset( $_POST['post_type'] ) && 'page' == $_POST['post_type'] ) {
if ( ! current_user_can( 'edit_page', $post_id ) ) {
return;
}
} else {
if ( ! current_user_can( 'edit_post', $post_id ) ) {
return;
}
}
if ( ! isset( $_POST['evn_from_date'] ) && 
! isset( $_POST['evn_from_time'] ) && 
! isset( $_POST['evn_to_date'] ) && 
! isset( $_POST['evn_to_time'] ) &&
! isset( $_POST['evn_timezone'] ) &&  

! isset( $_POST['evn_location'] )&&
! isset( $_POST['evn_link'] ) 
) {
return;
}

$evn_from_date = sanitize_text_field( $_POST['evn_from_date'] );
update_post_meta( $post_id, '_evn_from_date', $evn_from_date );

$evn_from_time = sanitize_text_field( $_POST['evn_from_time'] );
update_post_meta( $post_id, '_evn_from_time', $evn_from_time );

$evn_to_date = sanitize_text_field( $_POST['evn_to_date'] );
update_post_meta( $post_id, '_evn_to_date', $evn_to_date );

$evn_to_time = sanitize_text_field( $_POST['evn_to_time'] );
update_post_meta( $post_id, '_evn_to_time', $evn_to_time );

$evn_timezone = sanitize_text_field( $_POST['evn_timezone'] );
update_post_meta( $post_id, '_evn_timezone', $evn_timezone );

$evn_link = sanitize_text_field( $_POST['evn_link'] );
update_post_meta( $post_id, '_evn_link', $evn_link );

$evn_location = sanitize_text_field( $_POST['evn_location'] );
update_post_meta( $post_id, '_evn_location', $evn_location );
}
add_action( 'save_post', 'eventcalendar_save_meta_box_data' );
```

Comment: Please share the complete code

Comment: it is complete code when on line number 106 here
selected( $evn_timezone["$country->name"] , esc_attr("$country->name"), false);
I am getting error

Comment: What is `$data`? What does it contain? Where does it come from?

Comment: i am fetching json data in $data variable.

Answer (score 0):

It's probably failing because `Andorra` isn't a key in `$evn_timezone`.

Can you `var_dump($evn_timezone);` so we can see what that contains?

You can also add checks such as:

```
if(isset($evn_timezone[$country->name])) {
   selected($evn_timezone["$country->name"], esc_attr("$country->name"), false);
}
```

That way, if the country isn't in the array, you won't get an error.

Comment: it is just printing string(5) "Array" .

Comment: OK, so the type is correct - so you should be able to see 5 country names listed then - and I'm guessing that Andorra isn't on there? This means that you have countries in `$data` which are not in `$evn_timezone`.

Comment: yes you are right.

Answer (score 0):

Also I am editing your codes. It is not following the correct WP coding structure. I am simplifying it

```
wp_nonce_field( 'evn_timezone', 'evn_timezone_nonce' );
$evn_timezone = get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_evn_timezone', true );

echo '<select id="evn_timezone" name="evn_timezone" >';

    foreach ($data->countries as $country) {

        $selected = ( $evn_timezone[ $country->name ] == esc_attr( $country->name ) ) ? ' selected="selected"' : '';

        printf( '<option value="%s(%s)"%s>%s</option>', $country->abbr, $country->name, $selected, $country->name );
   }

echo '</select>';
```

Comment: Chinmoy Kumar Paul great error gone. But while clicking on submit select option data in not saving.

Comment: you will check the option value into the printf statement and your callback function of save_post hook.

Comment: no error is coming when i  use inspect element error showing there but not in browser so issue is there.

Comment: what is the code under save_post action?

Comment: Can you replace

`$selected = ( $country[ $country->name ] == esc_attr( $country->name ) ) ? ' selected="selected"' : '';
printf( '<option value="%s(%s)"%s>%s</option>', $country->abbr, $country->name, $selected, $country->name );`

**with**

`$selected = ( ! empty( $evn_timezone ) && $country->name == esc_attr( $evn_timezone ) ) ? ' selected="selected"' : '';

printf( '<option value="%s"%s>%s</option>', $country->name, $selected, $country->name );`

Comment: Chinmoy Kumar Paul you are awsome Problem Solved. Bundle of thanks.